# How to fetch Oxford Dictionary API in Next.js

Tags: next.js, fetch

I can't fetch Oxford Dictionary API with `next/router` params.

I already try an example I found, and it works well.\

```
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function Home() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { postId } = router.query;

  const [post, setPost] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    if (postId) {
      fetchPost(postId);
    } else {
      setPost({});
    }
  }, [postId]);
  let fetchPost = (postId) => {
    fetch(`https://gorest.co.in/public/v1/posts/${postId}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        setPost(response.data);
      });
  };
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      {post.id ? null : <h1>Try /?postId=500</h1>}
      {post.id ? (
        <div className={styles.fixedCard}>
          <div className={styles.number}>{post.id}</div>
          <h2>{post.title}</h2>
          <p>{post.body}</p>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

But it doesn't work after I rewrite it for fetching Oxford Dictionary API.

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function Home() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { entries } = router.query;

  const [wordData, setWordData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    if (entries) {
      fetchData(entries);
    } else {
      setWordData({});
    }
  }, [postId]);
> let fetchData = (entries) => {
    fetch(`https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v2/entries/en-us/${entries}`.{
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            app_id: 'xxxxxxxx',
            app_key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        setWordData(response.data);
      });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {wordData.results[0].id ? (
        <div>
          <h1>{wordData.results[0].lexicalEntries[0].entries[0].senses[0].definitions[0]}</h1>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```